# How to match one list with another only once, in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of list called list a, which has details of a registration id, and number of participants.

```
lista=[["222",3],["333",3],["122",4]]
```

And I have another list of list which has details of a apartment name and number of beds.

```
 listb=[["lily",4],["arnica",3],["maple",3],["aron",3]]
```

I need to match the lista second column with list b second column only once.

Since I am allocating the number of participants to number of beds, the matching of elements need to be done only once. Once the matching is done, I need the print out both the elements matched only once. I do not want multiple matches, I need a single match as follows:

```
listc=[["222",3,"arnica",3]]
```

I wrote the code:

```
for unit in list a:
    for nit in list b: 
        if unit[1]==nit[1]:
            print(unit,nit)
            lista.remove(unit[0])
            lista.remove(unit[1])
```

But it generates an error. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct, but you have to terminate the loop after you found the possible match otherwise you will get multiple matches.

I think this will work for you

```
lista=[["222",3],["333",3],["122",4]]

listb=[["lily",4],["arnica",3],["maple",3],["aron",3]]

for unit in lista :
    for nit in listb :
        if unit[1]==nit[1]:
            print(unit,nit)
            break
    listb.remove(nit)
```

output,

```
(['222', 3], ['arnica', 3])
(['333', 3], ['maple', 3])
(['122', 4], ['lily', 4])
```